# Mysql syntax error in insert query by selecting distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, distinct-values

My query shows an error(an expression was expected near DISTINCT), i dont know how to resolve it, if i remove the first INSERT query line, values are selecting properly, if i add insert it shows error, any help could be useful thanks in advance.

```
INSERT INTO normal_days (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
  SELECT DISTINCT clo.user_id, design.department_id , uses.designation_id, clo.date,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out
  FROM clock clo 
    INNER JOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date != clo.date
    INNER JOIN users AS uses ON clo.user_id = uses.id
    INNER JOIN designations AS design ON design.id = uses.designation_id
  WHERE date(clo.created_at) = "2016-06-23"
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out) = 28800
    AND !(DAYOFWEEK(clo.date)=7)
    AND !(DAYOFWEEK(clo.date)=1);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: an expression was expected near DISTINCT, unrecognised keyword near distinct.

Comment: That's not a mysql error, and apart from not doing what you probably expect (`INNER JOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date != clo.date` will not exclude holidays if you have more than 1 row in `holidays`), on first sight it looks syntactically fine for mysql. Are you using mysql? If yes, or add the actual error message. Or check your client, maybe it is something around this code you use to send this query to mysql, and it is actually an error of your client.

Comment: ya i use mysql only.

Comment: @Solarflare how to do if holidays table have more than one rows any suggestions pls.

Comment: Again, your error message is not a mysql error message, it is probably a message your client creates before it reaches mysql. For your holday table: `LEFTJOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date = clo.date` and then later in your where-clause `and hol.date is null`.

Comment: @Solarflare Thank you it worked for me..

Comment: @Solarflare add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO normal_days (user_id, department_id,designation_id,date_cur,clock_in,clock_out)
SELECT clo.user_id, design.department_id , uses.designation_id, clo.date, clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out
FROM clock clo 
LEFT JOIN holidays AS hol ON hol.date = clo.date
INNER JOIN users AS uses ON clo.user_id = uses.id
INNER JOIN designations AS design ON design.id = uses.designation_id
WHERE date(clo.created_at) = "2016-06-23" 
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,clo.clock_in, clo.clock_out) = 28800
AND !(DAYOFWEEK(clo.date)=7)
AND !(DAYOFWEEK(clo.date)=1)
AND hol.date is NULL ;
```